# Java Parsing - delimiter can also be part of the token

Tags: java, parsing, delimiter

I have a string to parse.

```
      M|N| | |"DANGER| AWESOME"|N|N| | | |
```

The delimiter is the pipe (|) symbol.  However the pipe can be part of the token.   In that case, it is enclosed in double quotes.  Is there an existing library/function that I can use that lets me specify a delimiter or an opening/closing delimiter (|" and "|).  StringTokenizer does not work since it would count the pipe in DANGER| AWESOME as a delimiter.   I feel like there must be a solution less tedious than checking the string character by character/creating a custom parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about?

```
String regex = "\\|(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)";
```

Testing:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String x = "M|N| | |\"DANGER| AWESOME\"|N|N| | | |";
    String regex = "\\|(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)"; 
    String[] y = x.split(regex);
    for(String s : y) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
    System.out.println("************* DONE ***********");
}
```

Output:

```
M
N


"DANGER| AWESOME"
N
N



************* DONE ***********
```

Comment: Thank you!!! Could you explain (or point me towards a site that breaks down) the regex pattern in words? My regex has always been horrible.

Comment: The only reason I know this one is because I ask about it (using commas instead of `|` as the separator). [Here is the link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20762375/need-a-breakdown-of-the-following-regular-expression)